# gdal_translate outfile without nodata_values

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, nodata, esri-ascii-raster, xyz

I want to use gdal_translate to convert a ASCII grid file onto a xyz file. But the ASCII grid is about 5.7Go and the xyz outfile is really bigger (approximately 30Go). To reduce the memory I would like to didn't store no data values but when I use -a no_data -9999 there is still lines into the xyz files like X Y -9999. It's a real problem for me, because they are useless and took too much place on my files.
Also, I saw that my decimals values (Z) are quite big ! Something like 10 decimal's numbers (350.1498736541). Is that possible to ask it to troncate after 2 decimals (350.14 or better : 350.15) ?

For now, I use gdal_translate like that :

> gdal_translate -of xyz -a_nodata -9999 Mosaic.asc  Mosaic.xyz

Comment: If you don't have the nodata values, how will your grid or xyz file have "voids" shown? Those values indicate the voids - gdal doesn't support files without them (http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html). You could probably find a better format (TIFF, maybe?), or trim the extent so avoid them. For the decimal precision part, try the `-co DECIMAL_PRECISION=2` option - I don't know if it works with XYZ, but its worth a shot.

Comment: Well, I'm agree for a raster but for a xyz file where each line is a point, if you have a point defined as nodata, it's useless. You don't need nodata values for a cloud points. You only need them for a raster when you want to have a regular grid or at least,  a grid.

XYZ file didn't support DECIMAL_PRECISION :(

Comment: Actually, I didn't write it on my post but I want a file with points only. So I think, xyz file is the best option (even if it's not optimize as a grid), we can say that I need a cloud point (to use it on an other library next: CGAL).

Comment: GDAL won't do that, but you could write a simple script to eliminate your unwanted points - just look for the `nodata` value.

Comment: yep, I finally used sed.
Thank's. I let the topic without answer, maybe on a next version it will be possible.